# Text falling out of box

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and when I use search this happens [link](http://budivelik.kgv-projekt.hr/?s=protein)

As you can see in first two description boxes, text is going out from description box because excpert text is to long, how can I modify css that all text will be only in my description box?

Comment: do you mean wrapping text ?

Comment: Add code instead of a link. Nobody should have to visit a website (specially if it's a store) to see what's failing. And now that the problem is solved, and you fixed the code, the issue is impossible to reproduce. I would almost consider this post as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overflow:hidden of div.
"And you can change max-height:100% of .blog-content"

```
.blog-content{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: this works! I marked your anwser as correct,  now it works :) you saved me

Answer (score 0):

change the `max-height:100px;` to `min-height:200px` so that doesn't exceed.

```
.blog-content.padding{
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: If content only of one or two line then will be appear empty space.

Comment: yep but I think his excerpt has a maximum character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property, which can have following values:

> - **normal**
>
>   Use the default line break rule.
> - **break-all**
>
>   Word breaks may be inserted between any character for non-CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) text.
> - **keep-all**
>
>   Don't allow word breaks for CJK text.  Non-CJK text behavior is same as normal.

In your case you should use `break-all` this way:

```
style='word-break: break-all;'
```